# Rails 3 - What's wrong with this CASE Statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<% @feed.each do |feed| %>

    <ul id="feed">

        <%= 
            case feed.action_type
            when "COMMENT"
                <%= render :partial => "feeds/storyitem" -%>,
            end
        %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest ERB tags like that -- you're trying to insert the `render...` ERB tag when you're already inside ERB. If that's what you really want to do, try this:

```
<% @feed.each do |feed| %>

    <ul id="feed">
        <% case feed.action_type
        when "COMMENT" %>
            <%= render :partial => "feeds/storyitem" -%>,
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

But unless you've simplified the code example for posting it here, the `<% if %>` looks clearer to me.

Answer (score -1):

ok figured it out:

```
<% @feed.each do |feed| %>

    <ul id="feed">

        <%= 
            case feed.action_type
            when "COMMENT"
                render :partial => "feeds/storyitem"
            end
        %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

no need for the <% around the render partial